# Unique URLs in plone

Tags: url, plone, xdv, linguaplone

I have an internal link to sectionA/pageA in a sidebar, when I click it from sectionB the url becomes sectionB/sectionA/post. I cannot use absolute URL because the sidebar is in an XDV static file and I use linguaplone.
How can I create unique url?

Answer (score 3):

What you see a combination of a relative URL (not starting with a `/` or full URL including protocol and hostname) and acquisition. The latter means that `sectionA` can be reached still after traversing over `sectionB`. You'll have to use absolute URLs in the sidebar.

If you use a templating method to generate the sidebar (a ZPT pagetemplate, XDV, Diazo, etc.) you'll have to ensure you generate an absolute URL by either querying pageA directly for it's absolute url or any of it's ancestors and then add to the URL from there. Here are three TAL snippets that would achieve that:

```
 <!-- query pageA directly -->
 <a href="sectionA/pageA" tal:attributes="href sectionA/pageA/absolute_url"/> 

 <!-- start at sectionA and add to the URL from there -->
 <a href="sectionA/pageA" tal:attributes="href string:$(sectionA/absolute_url}/pageA"/> 

 <!-- assuming sectionA is in the site root, use that as the start -->
 <a href="sectionA/pageA" tal:attributes="href string:$portal_url/sectionA/pageA"/>
```

If you use an external templating system such as XDV, the same principles apply, but you won't be able to directly query either sectionA or pageA for their absolute URLs, but you will have absolute URLs to reconstruct a URL to them available, like the `portal_url` in the last example.

Comment: Ok great but... I have installed linguaplone and with absolute url I don't preserve the correct language.

Comment: @martino: Is `pageA` a template that's language dependent? There is a I18N_LANGUAGE cookie that'll let you insert the language in the URL (http://site/en/sectionA/pageA), would that solve that for you?

Comment: Ok but if I have static XDV html I cannot use cookie. I think that the only method is put this static content in a static portlet, right?